# Java write exe file

Tags: java

is it possible to write/create an exe file in Java?
I can successfully read it but writing the exact same data that has been read to a new file seems to create some trouble because Windows tell's me it's not supported for my pc anymore.

This is the code I'm using to read the file where `path` is a `String` given with the actual `path` (it's in the `.jar` itself that's why I'm using `ResourceAsStream()`):

```
try {
    InputStream inputStream = FileIO.class.getResourceAsStream(path);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    ArrayList<String> _final = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        _final.add(line);
    }
    inputStream.close();
    return _final.toArray(new String[_final.size()]);
}catch(Exception e) {
    return null;
}
```

This is the code I'm using to write the file:

```
public static void writeFileArray(String path, String[] data) {
    String filename = path;
    try{
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(filename);
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
        for(String d : data) {
            bufferedWriter.write(d + "\n");
        }
        bufferedWriter.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ex){
        System.out.println("FileIO failed to write file, IO exception");
    }
}
```

So it doesn't give me any error's or something and the file size of the original .exe and the 'transferred' .exe stays the same, but it doesn't work anymore. Am I just doing it wrong? Did I forget something? Can u even do this with Java?

Btw I'm not that experienced with reading/writing files..

Thanks for considering my request.

Comment: Because the file is located originally in the .jar file but I wanna put it on the computer for ease of access for the use himself

Comment: Make sure you copied file permissions as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that you're using a `Reader` when you should be using a raw input stream.  Use [BufferedInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html) instead of `BufferedReader`.

```
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream( inputStream );
```

The problem is that `Reader` interprets the binary as your local character set instead of the data you want.

Edit: if you need a bigger hint start with this.  I just noticed you're using a `BufferedWriter` too, that won't work either.

```
try {
    InputStream inputStream = FileIO.class.getResourceAsStream(path);
    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream( inputStream );

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[ 1024 ];
    for( int length; ( length = ins.read( bytes ) ) != -1; )
       bos.write( bytes, 0, length );
    }
inputStream.close();
return bos;
```

Comment: This is what I got now, but now no data comes through ...[link](https://imgur.com/a/jptH7)

Comment: @JarnoG Try the `ByteArrayOutputStream` version I just posted.  Using `List<Interger>` instead is going to be very inefficient, at least.

Comment: Is that correct? I got 2 functions: write data and read data but it's all mixed up here?

Comment: Where is the outputstream even outputting it?

Comment: @JarnoG Yes that looks correct.  Make sure to test it.  Writing a `ByteArrayOutputStream` or a `byte[]` is three lines of code, you should be able to handle it.

Comment: When you use your own buffer (the `byte[]` array), there is no sense in additionally using a `BufferedInputStream`. All it does, is reading the original stream into an array and copying to your array. The only difference between these two arrays is the size, but you can simply make your array 8192 bytes large and have the same effect, but save the copying when not wrapping the `InputStream` into a `BufferedInputStream`.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Java 7 or newer, you should copy a resource to a file using

```
public static void copyResourceToFile(String resourcePath, String filePath) {
    try(InputStream inputStream = FileIO.class.getResourceAsStream(resourcePath)) {
        Files.copy(inputStream, Paths.get(filePath));
    }
    catch(IOException ex){
        System.out.println("Copying failed. "+ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This construct ensures correct closing of the resources even in the exceptional case and the JRE method ensures correct and efficient copying of the data.

It accepts additional options, e.g. to specify that the target file should be overwritten in case it already exists, you would use

```
public static void copyResourceToFile(String resourcePath, String filePath) {
    try(InputStream inputStream = FileIO.class.getResourceAsStream(resourcePath)) {
        Files.copy(inputStream, Paths.get(filePath), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    }
    catch(IOException ex){
        System.out.println("Copying failed. "+ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using InputStreams for strings, *.exe* files are bytes! 
Try using a ByteArrayInputStream and ByteArrayOutputStream.

Edit: completing with markspace's answer:

```
new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream( ... ) )
```

Comment: How would ByteArrayInputStream and ByteArrayOutputStream help with reading and writing files? They operate on in-memory byte arrays.